# How to compare 1 column in excel with other columns and give statistic (percentage) of how many match?

Tags: excel, compare, multiple-columns

How to compare 1 column in excel with other columns and give statistic (percentage) of how many match? For example I need to compare Columnn A with Column B, C, D, E, F. I will need to see statistic of Column A compared with each other column individually and also with all the other columns together.

I would really appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Comment: Please see [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

For **A** against **B**:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A20=B1:B20))/COUNTA(A:A)
```

for example:

[image]

Comment: Hi Gary thank you for your response. I forgot to mention the format in all the fields is text (countries).

Comment: Thank you. Would you mind telling me what is the best way to learn excel to the advanced level?